# Disable hotkey on vcl controls

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, access-keys

I do have a TPageControl that I do add and remove TTabsheet's from, and in the TTabsheets there are 2 TEdit's that the user can type firstname and lastname, when they do the Tab Caption does show what they have written.

But if the user add a '&' somewhere in the TEdit (and they are allowed to do) the tab do get the char after '&' as (underlined)hotkey..

So how do I disable a hotkey on a control.

Comment: Escape the & by adding another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to disable keyboard access key display on the control, you just need to double the ampersand character in the tab caption to let Windows know it should be displayed as a character instead of underlining the following character.